# How do I solve this Apollo Control Cache error?

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

I am trying to set up my server side backend and I'm hitting this error:

```
node_modules/apollo-cache-control/dist/index.d.ts:24:9 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'cacheControl' must be of type 'ResolveInfoCacheControl', but here has type '{ setCacheHint: (hint: CacheHint) => void; cacheHint: CacheHint; }'.

24         cacheControl: {
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/node_modules/apollo-server-types/dist/index.d.ts:140:9
    140         cacheControl: ResolveInfoCacheControl;
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'cacheControl' was also declared here.
```

Answer (score 3):

I just found a fix for this, You have to add this to your tsconfig.json file:

```
"skipLibCheck": true
```

My tsconfig.json looks like:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "lib": ["es6", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "types": ["node"],
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

And also make sure to have all apollo packages to have same exact version.

Comment: It is good that there is this workaround, but I'm not sure this is a good long-term solution as this will affect all libraries. I wonder if there is anything that can be done that is a bit more targeted to the offending library?

Comment: @David for now I am proceeding with this hack. I totally agree ith you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all apollo packages (`apollo-server`, `apollo-server-express`, `apollo-server-core`) have the exact same version

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a bad import. I was importing `import { VariableValues } from 'apollo-server-types/src'` instead of `import { VariableValues } from 'apollo-server-types'`

I swear it was the auto-importer....